# In ElasticSearch, how to get similarity value in percentage?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, search

I'm using **ElasticSearch** to search data and return it to Ruby on rails.

The similarity of the returned data is an integer(<%= hit._score.to_i %>), but how do I get the percentage?

Comment: What percentage do you mean? The score is usually a bit more complex and doesn't represent a percentage of "how exact" the match was.

Comment: FYI: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/lucene/ScoresAsPercentages